# "Order items" view displaying removed items (variations)?

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm dynamically removing items from cart with this function:

```
  static function _remove_product_variation_from_cart($variationId) {
    $orders = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider')->getCarts();
    if (empty($orders)) {
      return 0;
    }
    $items = reset($orders)->getItems();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
      $quantity = $item->getQuantity();
      $itemVariationId = $item->getPurchasedEntity()->id();
      if ($variationId == $itemVariationId){
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
          $order->removeItem($item)->save();
        }
        return $quantity;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

And during checkout process it's all fine - removed items are not displayed. But page:

```
/user/user_id/orders/order_id
```

is listing also removed items (that's view "Order items"). Sum (order total) is correct however.
On other hand i.e. view "Checkout Order Summary" is returning order items correctly (without removed ones).

Am I removing cart item wrong way or something? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $quantity = $item->getQuantity();
  $itemVariationId = $item->getPurchasedEntity()->id();
  if ($variationId == $itemVariationId){
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
      $cart_manager = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_manager');
      $cart_manager->removeOrderItem($order, $item);
    }
    return $quantity;
  }
}
// return 0; <-- not necessary, functions don't have to always return.
```

Comment: I'm passing variation id so only one will be found (using also combine carts module). As soon it's found, that's it - no more exist. As mentioned, on cart page and on order edit page everything is displayed well. Problem is only order view page.

Comment: @MilanG ok, try using the cart manager to remove item like I do here.

Comment: It works! Thank you a lot!